# Applet based application stopped working after upgrading to Java

Tags: java, applet

We recently upgraded the JDK on our Java application server from JRockit to Java 7. While most of the applications worked as expected, users for one of the applications reported issues. We ended up upgrading the JDK on the client nodes to get it to work. While it works for most users, some users are still complaining about intermittent pop up complaining about security warnings.

Obviously applets are quite old and should the application should be replaced. But I am not part of the software team and looking for any suggestions to deal with this issue.

Comment: Messages and exceptions, for example from Java Console are base to resolve problem. I have some similarity with government application (dedicated to some not current java version), carefully reading logs is helpful.

Comment: Applets are a deprecated technology, as you already know.  I'm surprised it is even running for everyone at all.